Passing value from dropdown (text) to another box
I'm having some trouble getting the text value from a dropdown selection. It is connected to mysql and it is passing the entry ID instead of the value. Can anyone help?
When I select one option, for example Product 1, instead of displaying "Product 1" it is displaying the entry ID from the mysql table.

In Selected UPC I need to see the same value as Select UP, but is showing "3" which is the ID in mysql.
This is what I'm using.


$("#sub_category_item").change(function() {
  $("#textArea").val(this.value);
}).change();
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Select UPC</label>
    <select name="sub_category_item" id="sub_category_item" class="form-control input-lg" data-live-search="true" title="Select UPC" onchange="getText(this)">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Selected UPC</label>
    <input type="textarea" class="form-control" id="textArea" name="textarea" onchange="getText(this)">
  </div>
</div>




where comes the mysql part in it?

Change $("#textArea").val(this.value); to $("#textArea").val(this.textContent);

Made a snippet of your code and added jQuery as it appeared to use that - update as needed but getText(this) the function this references is not defined.

Thank you for the help. It is working better now, displaying the "Selected UPC" text, but also adding the Box test. is it coming like:  Select UPC6947273701965 where should only be the numbers.
